# how can I bind the matched :or to a variable in core.match

Tags: clojure, core.match, clojure-core.match

how can I bind the matched `:or` or to a variable in core.match?

```
user=> (use 'clojure.core.match)
user=> (let [v 2]
  #_=>          (match [v]
  #_=>            [((:or 1 2) :as x)] [:foo  x]
  #_=>            :else :bar))

             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/jp/y5hpfwq962x476pm_1knzr8c0000gn/T/form-init7072120633012300984.clj:2:10)
user=>
```

Comment: Well, you can just get `[:foo v]` and avoid the capturing part, right? :)

Comment: not really, the code above is just minimal problem illustration. In practice, you can imagine a more complex scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that `core.match` doesn't allow `:or` patterns to be bound to symbol. But you always can emulate `:or` behavior with guards and guarded patterns can be bound to symbol:

```
(def v [1 2])

(match v
  [(x :guard #{1 2}) 2] [:foo x]
  :else :bar) ;; => [:foo 1]
```